# Create message queue with mqueue.h

Tags: c, posix

I am trying to create a posix message queue using `mq_open` from `<mqueue.h>`.

`MAX_MSG` and `MAX_MSG_LGTH` are macros currently defined as `256` and `name` is never longer than `MAX_MSG_LGTH`.

This is the code I currently have:

```c
mqd_t func(char* name)
{
    mqd_t queueId;
    char localbuffer[MAX_MSG_LGTH + 1];
    localbuffer[0] = '/';
    strncpy(&localbuffer[1], name, MAX_MSG_LGTH);
    localbuffer[MAX_MSG_LGTH] = '\0';

    struct mq_attr mqAttr = {0, MAX_MSG, MAX_MSG_LGTH, 0};

    queueId = mq_open(localbuffer, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 007, &mqAttr);

    return queueId;
}
```

- input: `"task1"`
- output: -1
- errno: 22 (EINVAL)

I have checked `localbuffer` and the queue name is being stored correctly (`"/task1"`).

Comment: It seems you don't have permission to run this. Try running again with `sudo`.

Comment: @JardelLucca this is compiled with a complex Makefile that I cannot alter and needs to be able to run without `sudo`. Is there another way to use `<mqueue.h>` without the necessity for `sudo`?

Comment: You are specifying `007` for the mode of the newly-created queue, which is pretty weird in that it gives the user themselves no access, and in that I don't know what execute access means for a message queue.  A bad mode is not documented as a reason for an `EINVAL`, but it is nevertheless a plausible cause.  If you want a world-accessible queue then I suggest mode `0666`.  If you want one accessible only to the user running the program then `0600`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MSG_MAX` value is [may be] too large.

I ran your code and I reduced `MSG_MAX` and [eventually] it worked.

---

To see the system-wide values you can use, try:

```
head -1000 /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/*
```

On my system, I got:

```
==> /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_default <==
10

==> /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max <==
10

==> /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msgsize_default <==
8192

==> /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msgsize_max <==
8192

==> /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/queues_max <==
256
```

Note that you *can* [as `root`] write to these files to change/increase the values.

---

Also, `MSG_MAX_LGTH` has nothing to do with the max size for the filename.

The max length for the filename is *always* 256.

---

Using `007` for a permission is a little screwy. It says that *other* users have full access, but *your* user has *none*.

I think you want `0700` or [better] `0600`. Note that the leading `0` is needed to interpret the value as *octal*.